# Registering a Serilog file logger for dependency injection in a .NET Core 3.0 WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, .net-core, serilog

I am developing a WinForms application in .NET Core 3.0. I would like to log debug information to a file. I saw that Serilog was a good option but I'm happy to consider alternatives too. I'd ideally like to get a reference to my logger in various classes using dependency injection.

Most of the articles and documentation I found focused on ASP .NET rather than WinForms, so I had to use my imagination a bit when setting up Serilog in my `Program`'s `static void Main()` method.

Did I do it right? Not exactly!

```
 public class Program
    {
        private static Logger _logger; // I noticed that you don't have to do
                                       // this in the ASP .NET samples as it's
                                       // taken care of "under the hood".
                                       // However, I couldn't see any
                                       // alternative in the standard
                                       // WinForms template in VS.

        private static void Main()
        {
            //Omitted some code about configuration files and WinForms initialization for brevity

            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ServiceProvider = ConfigureServices(services);

            Application.Run(Form1);
        }

        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(GetLogger(), true));
            GetLogger().Debug("Hello!!"); // Just testing... nothing happens. Where's my log file?
            //Omitted registration of various unrelated services for brevity

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }


        private static Logger GetLogger()
        {
            if(_logger is null)
            {
                _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(@"c:\BenjaminLog-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
            }

            return _logger;
        }
    }
}
```

My code builds and runs but no log file is created.

Answer (score 0):

The default log level (MinimumLevel) is Information. Because you don't specify a different log level when configuring your logger and your test message is logged at Debug level, it will not be processed. Try changing `GetLogger().Debug("Hello!!");` to `GetLogger().Information("Hello!!");`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! That was useful advice but still there is something else wrong. I have now changed the test line to `GetLogger().Information("Hello!!");` and even tried  `GetLogger().Critical("Hello!!");` I have also added the argument `restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug` into the configuration. Still no log is getting created.